# BeanStalk with Tomcat is not deploying war automatically

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have created a BeanStalk with Tomcat.
I have added my war via S3.

When I accessed to the domain I was seeing connection refused.

Now my war is running but I had to access via ssh, copy my war in webapps folder and run `tomcat start`

Why Beanstalk is not deploying automatically?